# Merging of two subroutines together

Tags: excel, vba, vcf-vcard

I have two modules running on my VBA excel file. I am wondering how I can merge the two modules together so I don't need to run two separate modules?

The first module extracts data from every .vcf file in a folder and inputs it into each excel cell on the first column A

```
Option Explicit
Sub getfiledata()
    
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim strString  As String
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xFolder As Folder
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set xFolder = fso.GetFolder("K:\VCF to QR Folder")
    
    iRow = 2 ' Row to start inserting data
    
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        
        If InStr(1, xFile.Name, ".vcf") <> 0 Then
        
            Dim lFile As Long
            Dim szLine As String
            
            lFile = FreeFile()
            
            Open xFile.Path For Input As lFile
            
            strString = ""
            While Not EOF(lFile)
            
                Line Input #lFile, szLine
            
                ' Concatenete lines from text file
                strString = strString & szLine & vbCrLf
                
            Wend
            
            ' Add to cell
            Cells(iRow, 1).Value = strString
            
            iRow = iRow + 1
            
            ' Close the file
            Close lFile
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        
        End If
        
    Next ' End of LOOP
    
    MsgBox "Completed!"
End Sub
```

And the second module, gets the file name of each of those .vcf files and inputs them in the same order in column B.

```
Sub getfilenames()
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    i = 2
    For n = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
        FnameInLoop = Right(FName(n), Len(FName(n)) - InStrRev(FName(n), _
        Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        Cells(i, 2).Value = FnameInLoop
        i = i + 1
    Next n
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can have one module just run these two 'actions' at once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copy & Paste ? ;-)

Comment: You don't need to use `Application.GetOpenFilename` at all ... A `File` has `.Name` property. So in the first subroutine, write `xFile.Name` into column B?